# Is it right to init multiprocess in class __init__?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, thread-safety

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
class TSNew:
    def __init__(self):
        self.redis_client = redis.StrictRedis(host="172.17.31.147", port=4401, db=0)
        self.global_switch = 0
        self.pool = ThreadPool(40) # init pool
        self.dnn_model = None
        self.nnf = None
        self.md5sum_nnf = "initialize"
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.load_model_item)
        self.ts_picked_ids = None
        self.thread.start()

        self.memory = deque(maxlen=3000)
        self.process = threading.Thread(target=self.process_user_dict)
        self.process.start()

    def load_model_item(self):
        '''
        code
        '''
    def predict_memcache(self,user_dict):
        '''
        code
        '''
    def process_user_dict(self):
        while True:
            '''
            code to generate user_dicts which is a list 
            '''
            results = self.pool.map(self.predict_memcache, user_dicts)
            '''
            code
            '''
TSNew_ = TSNew()

def get_user_result():
    logging.info("----------------come in ------------------")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_dict_json = request.get_data()# userid
        if user_dict_json == '' or user_dict_json is None:
            logging.info("----------------user_dict_json is ''------------------")
            return ''
        try:
            user_dict = json.loads(user_dict_json)
        except:
            logging.info("json load error, pass")
            return ''
        TSNew_.memory.append(user_dict)
        logging.info('add to deque TSNew_.memory size: %d  PID: %d', len(TSNew_.memory), os.getpid())
        logging.info("add to deque userid: %s, nation: %s \n",user_dict['user_id'],  user_dict['user_country'])
        return 'SUCCESS\n'


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def get_ts_gbdt_id():
    return get_user_result()

from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=4444)
```

I create a multi thread pool in class `__init__` and I use the `self.pool`
to map the function of `predict_memcache`.
I have two doubts:
(a) Should I initialize the pool in `__init__` or just init it right before

```
results = self.pool.map(self.predict_memcache, user_dicts)
```

(b) Since the pool is a multi thread operation and it is executed in the thread of `process_user_dict`, so is there any hidden error ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Question (a):**

It depends. If you need to run `process_user_dict` more than once, then it makes sense to start the pool in the constructor and keep it running. Creating a thread pool always comes with some overhead and by keeping the pool alive between calls to `process_user_dict` you would avoid that additional overhead.

If you just want to process one set of input, you can as well create your pool right inside `process_user_dict`. But probably not right before `results = self.pool.map(self.predict_memcache, user_dicts)` because that would create a pool for every iteration of your surrounding `while` loop.

In your specific case, it does not make any difference. You create your `TSNew_` object on module-level, so that it remains alive (and with it the thread pool) while your app is running; the same thread pool from the same `TSNew` instance is used to process all the requests during the lifetime of `app.run()`.
Since you seem to be using that construct with `self.process = threading.Thread(target=self.process_user_dict)` as some sort of listener on `self.memory`, creating the pool in the constructor is functionally equivalent to creating the pool inside of `process_user_dict` (but outside the loop).

**Question (b):**

Technically, there is no hidden error by default when creating a thread inside a thread. In the end, any additional thread's ultimate parent is always the `MainThread`, that is implicitly created for every instance of a Python interpreter. Basically, every time you create a thread inside a Python program, you create a thread in a thread.

Actually, your code does not even create a thread inside a thread. Your `self.pool` is created inside the `MainThread`. When the pool is instantiated via `self.pool = ThreadPool(40)` it creates the desired number (40) of worker threads, plus one worker handler thread, one task handler thread and one result handler thread. All of these are child threads of the `MainThread`. All you do with regards to your pool inside your thread under `self.process` is calling its `map` method to assign tasks to it.

However, I do not really see the point of what you are doing with that `self.process` here.
Making a guess, I would say that you want to start the loop in `process_user_dict` to act as kind of a listener on `self.memory`, so that the pool starts processing `user_dict` as soon as they start showing up in the `deque` in `self.memory`. From what I see you doing in `get_user_result`, you seem to get one `user_dict` per request. I understand that you might have concurrent user sessions passing in these dicts, but do you really see benfit from `process_user_dict` running in an infinite loop over simply calling `TSNew_.process_user_dict()` after `TSNew_.memory.append(user_dict)`? You could even omit `self.memory` completely and pass the dict directly to `process_user_dict`, unless I am missing something you did not show us.